# Convert an 8bit number to hex in z80 assembler

Tags: hex, decimal, z80

I am writing a game for the ZX Spectrum using z80 and have a bit of a problem.
I have manipulated a routine to convert a number held in the “a” register to a hex value held in “de”. I’m not sure of how to convert the other way, EG pass in a hex value in de and convert this to decimal held in “a”.

NB: The following routine converts the input to the ascii values that represent the values 0 through to F. EG if a = 255 then d =70 and e = 70 as “F” is ascii value 70.

```
NumToHex    ld c, a   ; a = number to convert
            call Num1
            ld d, a
            ld a, c
            call Num2
            ld e, a
            ret  ; return with hex number in de

Num1        rra
            rra
            rra
            rra
Num2        or $F0
            daa
            add a, $A0
            adc a, $40 ; Ascii hex at this point (0 to F)   
            ret
```

Can anyone advise on a solution to work this in reverse or offer a better solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code takes DE has a hexadecimal number in ASCII and converts it to binary in A.  It assumes that DE is a valid hexadecimal number and uses uppercase 'A' through 'F'.  It will fail if lowercase letters are used or any ASCII character outside of '0' .. '9' and 'A' .. 'F'.

```
HexToNum ld   a,d
         call Hex1
         add  a,a
         add  a,a
         add  a,a
         add  a,a
         ld   d,a
         ld   a,e
         call Hex1
         or   d
         ret

Hex1     sub  a,'0'
         cp   10
         ret  c
         sub  a,'A'-'0'-10
         ret
```

Update: Have now tested code and fixed bug in handling of 'A' .. 'F' case in Hex1.

Update: Using "add a,a" which is faster than "sla a".  Note that if speed is a concern both conversions can be done much more quickly with lookup tables.

Comment: Many thanks for this. It does just what I need it to do.